# Heroku: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm able to precompile assets for a push to Heroku of an Enki blog, I migrated the database successfully. But then when I tried to run `heroku open` i got the error message page on Heroku (the app works locally). I then ran `heroku logs`and saw this error

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

Can anyone explain what the problem might be?

```
Processing by HomesController#index as HTML
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_request.text.erb (0.2ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_session.text.erb (0.3ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.0ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_environment.text.erb (13.9ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.0ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_backtrace.text.erb (0.1ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/exception_notification-2.5.2/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb (18.4ms)
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open'
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:549:in `block in do_start'
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2034:in `do_delivery'
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
2012-07-12T06:14:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:549:in `do_start'
```

**Update**

It was trying to send an email because to inform me of another error. Once I turned off the email, it gave me this for the error message. I can't find undefined method/Nil Class would be its referring to.

```
Started GET "/" for 24.84.41.17 at 2012-07-12 17:44:12 +0000
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomesController#index as HTML
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered homes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 99ms
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:20:in `encode_if_needed'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/field.rb:169:in `new_field'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass):
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/encodings.rb:181:in `address_encode'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/field.rb:169:in `new'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/field.rb:156:in `create_field'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/encodings.rb:189:in `encode_non_usascii'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/encodings.rb:184:in `address_encode'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/encodings.rb:181:in `block in address_encode'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/encodings.rb:181:in `map'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/fields/to_field.rb:42:in `initialize'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:9:in `parse'
2012-07-12T17:44:12+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/field.rb:87:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to send email from your app - Heroku does not provide any mail services with their platform. You will need to use a third party like SendGrid (They have a Heroku addon) to be able to send SMTP email.

Answer (score 19):

Error is due to you are trying to send email. Heroku does not provide an outgoing mail service but does allow the use of an external SMTP server. To enable free Sendgrid add-on: `$ heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter`.

```
#Set config/environment.rb

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Then Configure your SMTP connection.

`ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address  => "smtp.someserver.net",
  :port  => 25,
  :user_name  => "someone@someserver.net",
  :password  => "mypass",
  :authentication  => :login
}`

**Note:**-  free Sendgrid add-on limited(*send up to 200 emails per day.*).

Comment: thanks for your answer. it helped me. btw, the following page has more detail configuration information. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid